# How to ignore some part of characters from output result

Tags: cucumber, bdd, scenarios

I have to assert a string, i want to skip some characters

suppose

I have expected result value ABCDEFGHIJKLM, and my output will ABCDXYGHIZKLM. it should pass my bdd.

note :- my string length will be same for every time.

Comment: Does the position of the random chars defined? Can you always ignore the chars at 5,6,10 position while compare the 2 strings?

Comment: Yes, everytime i will get a fixed lenth string, and in that all characters will have same value except some characters, but the position will be fixed @supputuri

Comment: Do you mean 5,6,8 are the only positions that will have random chars?

Comment: Yes , correct @supputuri

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below logic.

```
String a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM";
String b = "ABCDXYGHIZKLM";

String tempA = a.substring(0, 4) + a.substring(6, 8)+a.substring(10);
String tempB = b.substring(0, 4) + b.substring(6, 8)+b.substring(10);
System.out.println(tempA);
System.out.println(tempB);

if (tempA.equals(tempB)){
    System.out.println("pass");
}
else {
    System.out.println("failed");
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @supputuri for your support and quick response, but i am writing BDDs, and using cucumber for assertion.

Comment: you have to implement this logic in your step def or pager level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hamcrest matchers for this.

```
import static org.hamcrest.text.MatchesPattern.matchesPattern;
assertThat("ABCDXYGHIZKLM", matchesPattern("ABCD.{2}GHI.KLM"));
```

add this to POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```